# Criar um id para um elemento a partir de uma condição com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma forma em *JavaScript* ou *jQuery* de incluir um `Id` em uma `div` dentro de uma condição?

Em meu código vou exemplificar:

```
 $('#TxtDesc').on('input', function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   var progressValue = $('#progressText div');
   var color, percent = 0;
if(value.length <= 100){
  color = "red";
  percent = 15;
}else if(value.length <= 199){
  color = "yellow";
  percent = 50;
}else{
  color = "#32CD32";
  percent = 100;
  /* Gostaria que nessa condição fosse adicionado um id 
    para a div onde o script roda */
}

 var Valor = value.length;



progress(percent, $('#progressText'), 300);
progressValue.css("background", color);
$('#progressText').css("border", "1px solid " + color);

 });
```

Existe alguma forma disso ser feito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for só adicionar ou trocar o atributo `id`, basta fazer:

```
$(this).attr('id', 'SeuValor');
```

No caso,

```
$(this)
```

faz referência à quem disparou o evento de 'input'. Mas você pode trocar para outro seletor livremente. Porém, não sei se trocar o `id` é uma boa ideia, então você poderia adicionar outro atributo:

```
$(this).attr('SeuAtributo', 'SeuValor');
```

Leia mais sobre a função `.attr()` [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo, porem eu queria isso, para que outra função pudesse encontrar esse informação, porém ao mudar o id, ele não conta esse Id novo

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você consiga utilizando a função data do jQuery:

```
$('div').data('id','valor-do-id');
```

No Html será gerado algo desse tipo:

```
<div data-id="valor-do-id"></div>
```

Você consegue capturar os dados dessa forma:

```
var id = $('div').data('id');
```

Fazendo desta forma não é necessário modificar o atributo id do elemento.